# How to raise a custom exception in Odoo 10?

Tags: exception, odoo, odoo-10

### Can i have a custom title in validation error/warning in odoo,I don't want Odoo in the title.

I have tried this code

```
raise odoo.osv.osv.except_osv('title', 'description')
```

But the title gets ignored.

Answer (score 5):

If I know well, by default you can not. However Odoo developers kept backward compatibility. When you use `except_orm`, then it will show your title text.

In my opinion this is not enough beauty solution.

```
from odoo import exceptions, _
...
raise exceptions.except_orm(_('My Title), _('My message + lorem ipsum'))
```

Result popup window:
[image]

Comment: I got a warning message, saying that `except_orm` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by this way,

1. Import the library
2. Generate error through following code,

   from odoo.osv import osv

   raise osv.except_osv((Error Condition), (Error Description))